# Move a vector<T*> to vector<const T*>

Tags: c++, vector, constants

Is it possible to move a `vector<T*>` to a `vector<const T*>` without copying it and without relying on `reinterpret_cast<>`? I.e.

```
vector<int*> get() {
   return ...;
}

vector<const int*> getConst() {
   return whatgoeshere(get());
}
```

Comment: Probably not...

Comment: This is where people start asking why do you want to do this? This sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You could add constness to the vector with `const_cast` but not to the elements inside them without copying them.

Comment: propagate_const?

Comment: And why are you worried about copies if you return by value anyway?

Comment: @StoryTeller: Looks interesting but I don't see exactly how it applies here. And re copies, it is easy to achieve this like: `auto tmp = get(); return {tmp.begin(), tmp.end()};` but that creates an additional unnecessary copy.

Comment: You return a vector by value. RVO or not, the target object has its buffer initialized

Comment: You know, I think the crux of it is the `...` you omitted. How is the return value created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to attack this from another angle. And address a possible design issue. You didn't specify what comes in the `...`, but assuming `get` populates a vector and then returns it, the solution in my view is to lift the code that does the populating outside of *both* functions.

```
template<typename Int>
void do_get(std::vector<Int*>& v) {
  // Populate v
}

auto get() {
   std::vector<int*> ret;
   do_get(ret);
   return ret;
}

auto getConst() {
   std::vector<const int*> ret;
   do_get(ret);
   return ret;
}
```

One source of truth for the populating logic. And while the two original functions are identical, it's negligible. Furthermore on a sane implementation it won't do any superfluous copies, because RVO is amazing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I must confess to not inferring that upon a first read through your answer. And I feel like any minute the OP will pull the rug from under this. I hate `...` in code.

Comment: Have A, need B. Can't convert A to B. Solutions: start with B instead of A, or end with A instead of B. You have shown the former ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Well, it's obvious when you spell it out :p

Comment: A B C D E F G... :D

Comment: This is a pretty clever solution, thanks. Technically, it doesn't answer the question but in my case you are correct about the `...`.

Answer (score 4):

**No.**

Although a `T*` may be trivially converted to a `const T*`, a container of `T*` is not "related" to a container of `const T*`, so there is simply no functionality to do what you ask.

Consider also that such functionality might hypothetically assign a `int**` to a `const int**`, which is not permitted (there is no special case provided for when the programmer intended this assignment to take place as part of a swap operation, as far as I know).

Furthermore, a `reinterpret_cast` would merely be hacking over these facts, giving your program undefined behaviour.

You are stuck with three options:

- Copy the vector (*O(n)*)
- Make it so that you have the container you wanted in the first place (*O(∞)*)
- Make it so that you don't need the new container type at all (*O(?)*)